# How to select N records from a table in mysql

Tags: mysql

How can I get only 10 records from a table where there are more than 1000 records. I have a test table with rowid, name, cost.

```
   select  name, cost from test;
```

here I want to select only first 10 rows and dont want to select rowid.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

To select the first ten records you can use LIMIT followed by the number of records you need:

```
SELECT name, cost FROM test LIMIT 10
```

To select ten records from a specific location, you can use LIMIT 10, 100

```
SELECT name, cost FROM test LIMIT 100, 10
```

This will display records 101-110

```
SELECT name, cost FROM test LIMIT 10, 100
```

This will display records 11-111

To make sure you retrieve the correct results, make sure you ORDER BY the results too, otherwise the returned rows may be random-ish

You can read more @ http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm

Comment: Personally, I'd always use an ORDER BY with a LIMIT to guarantee consistent, repeatable results.

Comment: I believe there is an error in your second example. In my tests, `LIMIT 10, 100` returns 100 records, beginning with index 11. `LIMIT 100, 10` returns 10 records starting with index 101.

Comment: `LIMIT 10` returns less than 10 records sometime, so this is not correct answer for me, so how can i select exactly 10 records?, not less and more . I used command line to execute this `limit` query, i run this query for 8 times at 7th time i got 8 records not 10 records.

Answer (score 9):

You should have an `ORDER BY` clause when you use [`LIMIT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html), so that you will get the same recordset if you call it two times in succession and no data has changed.

So, do something like:

```
select  name, cost 
from test 
order by rowid
limit 10;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT TOP(10) name, cost FROM test;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this query, you can get first 10 records.

```
SELECT employee_id, first_name 
FROM employees  
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

using below query can get first N records
suppose N=10

```
SELECT name, cost FROM test LIMIT 10;
```

suppose you want to get 10 records starting from the row M then (row index start from 0)

```
SELECT name, cost FROM test LIMIT 10 OFFSET (M-1);
```